# Рандомайзер слов в массиве

Tags: c++, строки, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно написать рандомайзер слов,который берет с клавиатуры 6 букв,записывает их в "алфавит" и потом делает рандомные слова,рандомной длины,используя буквы из "алфавита".Количество слов от 9 до 12.Пока добился того,что получается 1 рандомное слово и записывается в массив `Slovaa` 
Сам код .
P.s.Выходит ошибка компилятора,тип многократное обращение к массиву.Также подчеркивает мое стремное условие и строчку `Slovo[7] = { 0 }`,мол,массив имеет 7 байт,но может потребоваться 11,а в строчке,которую привел выше - массив имеет 7 байт,но может потребоваться 8.

P.S.S.Посоветуйте в каком направлении идти,скорее всего я тут уже полез далеко в дебри,но хотелось что-то похожее получить,только работающее:)Заранее спасибо

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "alphabet.h"
using namespace std;

void Alphabet(char* arr)  //алфавит
{
    cout << "Введите 6 букв вашего алфавита: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i]; //Ввод букв для слов
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0, "RU");
    srand(time(NULL));
    char arr[6];
    Alphabet(arr);

    TextRewrite objTextRewrite;  //заготовка под класс

    string sentence[20];   //массив предложений,состоящий из слов
    string Podlejashie[4]; //массив слов,которые будут ставиться в предложении на место подлежащего
    string Skazuemoe[4]; //массив слов,которые будут ставиться в предложении на место сказуемого
    string Glagol[4]; //массив слов,которые будут ставиться в предложении на место глагола
    char Slovo[7];  //само слово,которое будет улетать в рандомный массив 1-3 слово,изначально хотел обнулять этот массив,чтобы 
                    //использовать только 1 массив  
    int countOfWords = rand() % 3 + 9;  // колличество слов в предложении
    int count = -1; //счетчик слов,планировал с помощью него выйти из цикла,когда заполнится массив слов

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfWords; i++)  // цикл задачи слов
    {
        count++;  

        Slovo[i] = arr[rand() % 6 + 1]; //рандомная генерация слов из алфавита,но не понял,как играться с длиной слова,чтобы и она была рандомной
        if (Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[0] || Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[1] || Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[2] || Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[3] || Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[4] || Slovo[countOfWords - 1] == arr[5]) // просто ужасное условие,сам знаю,буду рад,если подскажите как исправить,проверяет на "готовность" слова,то бишь,до конца оно сгенерировалось или нет
        {
            Podlejashie[i] = Slovo; //собсна,само присваение массиву слов сгенерированного слова
            Slovo[7] = { 0 }; //попытка обнулить массив,хотя сам не понимаю зачем уже это делал
        }
        if (count == countOfWords - 1) // тут выход из цикла,если массив слов заполняется
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)  //тест вывода
    //  cout << Slovaa[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне кажется, примерно то, что вы хотите:

```
string alphabet;
cin >> alphabet;

int wordsCount = 9 + rand()%4;  // Случайное количество слов
for(int i = 0; i < wordsCount; ++i)
{
    int wordLength = 5 + rand()%10;  // Случайная длина слова
    string word;
    for(int j = 0; j < wordLength; ++j)
        word += alphabet[rand()%alphabet.length()];
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

Посмотрите, как работает - и можете переделать свой код. Конечно, по хорошему, нужно использовать в 2020 году `<random>`, но это вопрос второй :) Ну и понятно, что вместо вывода слов делаете с ними то, что вам нужно...

Пример работы - [тут](https://ideone.com/lXSsok).

Comment: Спасибо за совет,но я слегка не понял,как можно достать отдельные слова из массива word?Мне еще надо предложения из них делать,поэтому интересует,попробовал через цикл вывести,но,как я понял,у вас в цикле буквы записаны друг за другом в весь массив,а есть вариант,как записывать их в виде `string a = {"asd","dsa","zxc"}`,а не `string a = {"asddsazxc"}`,есть ли возможность записывать их в массив word именно так?

Comment: `word` - не массив, а отдельное слово!

Comment: Ох,точно,спасибо,что-то уж совсем тупые ошибки